# How to distinguish old-fashioned textbook from online textbook?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

My son's school has two versions of Geometry, which he will take next year.  One version uses an online textbook.  The other doesn't, in other words, it uses a ___________.  What word or phrase may I put in the blank, aside from "old-fashioned paper and cardboard" or "actual book"?

Sample usage (must not be deprecating tone):

> From your explanation of the difference between R and H Geometry, I would have thought R would be a good fit for my younger son.  But then I read that R uses an online text and H uses a ______________ book.  He has had a lot of trouble using online resources.  I step away for three seconds to let the cat out, and he's opened another tab and is watching Monty Python, NBA basketball, or what have you.  It's part of his OCD.

E.g. "an actual book" conveys my idea but I'm hoping for something more graceful.

Comment: "Physical textbook" as opposed to "digital textbook"

Comment: ***Paper vs digital***  is the common comparison you often  read or talk about : https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=paper+vs+digital&* - so I'd use the expression "paper book".

Comment: @Josh - "paper book" doesn't sound good, somehow.

Comment: *Paper Books Vs. eBooks: The State of the Art of Reading* - http://www.huffingtonpost.com/suren-ramasubbu/paper-books-vs-ebooks-the_b_9890584.html - *Are Paper Books Better Than E-Books?* - https://learning.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/09/25/are-paper-books-better-than-e-books/?_r=0

Comment: Check also here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paper+books%2Cdigital+books%2Cphysical+books&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpaper%20books%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdigital%20books%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphysical%20books%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Printed books is the more common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paper+books%2Cdigital+books%2Cphysical+books%2Cprinted+books%2Cprint+books&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpaper%20books%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdigital%20books%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphysical%20books%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprinted%20books%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprint%20books%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Depending on your eco-credentials, you might call the physical copy a [dead tree edition,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dead+tree+edition%22) as per *About 1,470 results* in Google Books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  you really need to click on the pages beneath Google's prognostics. https://www.google.it/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dead+tree+edition%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=zmq5WKO6MIayUfDmvOgG#q=%22dead+tree+edition%22&tbm=bks&start=40&* It seems there are far fewer than the circa 1,500 results. And how many teachers would actually refer to a paper based book as a "dead tree edition" in class?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: I don't know exactly how the Google Books algorithms work, but a year or two ago they changed the user interface to stop returning results much sooner anyway. And I have to say I can easily imagine a British teacher using such a [mock-]disparaging term, particularly with a class of older children who've all got access to smartphones, e-readers and tablets anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've generally heard _dead-tree edition_ among computer programmers and other technical workers (for whom the most useful and up-to-date information is typically online); the term is informal and joking even if it's no longer particularly funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for a publishing company, and we call our online books "e-books" and our printed books ... well ... "printed books." (So I concur with @Josh 's comments above.)

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-book) has a suprisingly complete explanation of e-books and their evolution:

> An electronic book (or e-book) is a book publication made available in digital form, consisting of text, images, or both, readable on the flat-panel display of computers or other electronic devices. Although sometimes defined as "an electronic version of a printed book," some e-books exist without a printed equivalent.

So, I would write that one sentence in your paragraph like this:

> But then I read that R uses an e-book and H uses a printed book.

(Note the article *an*, not *a*, before e-book.)

Answer (score 5):

Various possibilities; among the more common are *hard copy* and *print* (or *printed*) *textbook*).

Comment: +1 for *hard copy.*  Hardcopy/softcopy are very commonly used to distinguish between physical and electronic versions of documents in the working world.